# How to enable horizontal scroll in browsers on a mouse with separate horizontal scroll (logitech mx)?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, mouse, web-browser, macos

It's really frustrating that in Safari, Chrome when i use the horizontal scroll it switches between tabs instead of scrolling the page.
I've tried to go through the settings but found nothing on it. I would be grateful for advice.

Comment: You mention Logitech MX in your title. Are you referring to an MX Master mouse? Because if so, then I would recommend downloading the Logitech Options from https://www.logitech.com/de-de/product/options and you can configure every button the way you want.

Comment: @X_841yes, it's mx master. i can configure buttons, sure, but the scroll wheel action interpretation is specific per app.

Comment: No it is not. I have an Mx Master and the horizontal scroll wheel does not switch between tabs in Safari and Chrome. Instead it horizontally scrolls the web page. Make sure you have selected "all applications" in the logi options and set the thumb scroll wheel to "horizontal scroll". If that doesnt work try reinstalling the logi options toll.

Comment: ffs, you're right! Thanks @X_841 I had it set like that but I didn't see Safari entry on the list where it was set to switching tabs... awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @X_841 adding the chrome (or any app) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

With the updated version of Logi Options+ you need to make sure you change the option specifically for your browser.

Comment: It would be beneficial to future readers of your answer if you added screenshots/documentation of how to do what you propose.